# How to synchronously read a string encoded in CSV format in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, string, csv, decode

I want to read a string that is encoded in CSV format synchronously in Node.js. (***I don't want to read a CSV file asynchronously***).

To illustrate, below is asynchronous code to read a CSV file in Node.js. This code works well.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv
const { parse } = require("csv-parse");

const readCSV = () => {
  fs.createReadStream("./testfile.csv").pipe(
    parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 1 })
      .on("data", function (row) {
        console.log(row);
      })
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log("finished");
      })
      .on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
  );
};
```

Below is the content of `testfile.csv`. Although it's just one line, *it is not an easy one (notice the the multiple special characters and commas, arbitrarily placed for the purposes of this test)*, and it is best handled with a proper CSV parser.

```
Guatemala,United States,"Congo, ""Dem."" Rep. 'of' `the` (Kinshasa)",other country name
```

## How do I read the same content as an encoded string in Node.js?

Below is the same example as an encoded string in Node.js which I wish to read synchronously. Notice that I had to escape the `'` characters given the syntax of the language.

```js
  const encodedString = 'Guatemala,United States,"Congo, ""Dem."" Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)",other country name';
```

I came across this problem for two reasons:

1. I wish to encode a Node.js array as a string that can handle special characters and commas (and decode it as needed); and
2. I couldn't figure how to use the [CSV package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) (or any other package, I really looked at a lot of them) for strings. That is, they seem to always assume that you will be reading a CSV file with the `fs` package asynchronously; while my use case assumes that I already have the data encoded as a string variable. Thus, I also wish to do it synchronously, for there's no reason to do it differently since I am not getting the data from a stream.

I've already looked a lot of Stack Overflow questions ([How do I read the contents of a Node.js stream into a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623798/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-node-js-stream-into-a-string-variable), [Is there a way to read CSV in node.js synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66284057/is-there-a-way-to-read-csv-in-node-js-synchronously), etc.), and all I could find is examples of how to read a CSV *file asynchronously*. So the solution to this basic question is still missing.

## To summarize

A successful answer to this question will be the one that provides a function to ***decode*** the `encodedString` variable into an array like the one below. An even more ideal answer would also provide the corresponding function to ***encode*** the Node.js array into the same original encoded string.

```
[
  'Guatemala',
  'United States',
  'Congo, "Dem." Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)',
  'other country name',
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned how to use the `csv-parse` package synchronously. It is in fact supported by the package. You just need to import the synchronous version of the module. See documentation here https://csv.js.org/parse/api/sync/.

Below is a script that can handle the encoded string I provided as an example.

```js
// https://csv.js.org/parse/api/sync/
const { parse } = require("csv-parse/sync");

const decodeCSVStringSync = () => {
  const encodedString =
    'Guatemala,United States,"Congo, ""Dem."" Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)",other country name';

  const records = parse(encodedString, { delimiter: ",", from_line: 1 });

  console.log(records[0]);
};

decodeCSVStringSync();
```

Output:

```
[
  'Guatemala',
  'United States',
  'Congo, "Dem." Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)',
  'other country name'
]
```

And below is the corresponding function to encode an array of data into an string that follows the CSV format. (The output is the original encoded string.)

```js
//https://csv.js.org/stringify/options/cast/#field-level-options
const { stringify } = require("csv-stringify/sync");

const encodeArrayToCSVStringSync = () => {
  const arrayData = [
    "Guatemala",
    "United States",
    "Congo, \"Dem.\" Rep. 'of' `the` (Kinshasa)",
    "other country name",
  ];

  const encodedString = stringify([arrayData]);

  console.log(encodedString);
};

encodeArrayToCSVStringSync();
```

Output:

```
Guatemala,United States,"Congo, ""Dem."" Rep. 'of' `the` (Kinshasa)",other country name
```

Answer (score 0):

The csv-parse expects to act on streams not strings. But you can easily create your own ReadableStream and push your string into it.

```js
const Readable = require('stream').Readable
const { parse } = require("csv-parse")

const stream = new Readable()
const encodedString = 'Guatemala,United States,"Congo, ""Dem."" Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)",other country name'
stream.push(encodedString)
stream.push(null)

stream.pipe(
    parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 1 })
    .on("data", (row) => {
        console.log(row);
    })
    .on("error", (error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
    })
)
```

Output:

```
[
  'Guatemala',
  'United States',
  'Congo, "Dem." Rep. \'of\' `the` (Kinshasa)',
  'other country name'
]
```

Comment: I learned how to do it by using the sync version of the package @simon.ro. See my answer.